# code name one button shadow

Tags: button, codenameone

I have one button with blue bg color and I want to add black shadow as shown in the image,
how can be done in codenameone ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things.

The simplest is that when you cut the 9-piece border you can just include the shadow as part of the image: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-9-piece-image-border.html

You can also use a LayeredLayout and place the button within then place a shadow button in the bottom layer.